# Responsive named grid-template-columns?

Tags: css, css-grid

How does the naming `grid-template-columns` work in relation to media queries and responsiveness?

I'm trying to learn this and started with a very basic 2 column grid, from tablet and above its a 50/50 grid however, tablet below i want it on top of each other.

I'm using the fr unit so 1fr for each side when i want it 50/50 but how do it tell it to ignore that on mobile?

`auto` doesn't seem to work and neither does `100%`.

This is what i have so far. Grid setup:

```
.f-2-grid {
  grid-template-columns: [left-side] auto [right-side] auto;
}

@media (min-width: 46.25em) {
  .f-2-grid {
    grid-template-columns: [left-side] 1fr [right-side] 1fr;
  }
}
```

Targeting the 2 columns:

```
.footer-contact.f-2-grid-box {
  grid-column: left-side;
}

.follow-icons.f-2-grid-box {
  grid-column: right-side;
}
```

I'm sure this is a simple idea and apologies for the simple question but cannot seem to find the correct way from all the tutorials I've read.

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to have only one colum on mobile, define only one:

```
@media (min-width: 46.25em) {
  .f-2-grid {
    grid-template-columns: 100%;
  }
}
```

And you should probably remove the explicit grid-column property since it will only be 1 column.

I'm not sure if that's what you were asking.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, it set me on the right track... this did the trick...

```
.f-2-grid {
  /*nothing needed here*/
}

@media (min-width: 46.25em) {
  .f-2-grid {
    grid-template-columns: [left-side] 1fr [right-side] 1fr;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 46.25em) {
  .footer-contact.f-2-grid-box {
    grid-column: left-side;
  }
}


@media (min-width: 46.25em) {
  .follow-icons.f-2-grid-box {
    grid-column: right-side;
  }
}
```